# How many states two lines can have in $\mathbb R^4$ space?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

It is obvious that two lines in $\mathbb R^3$ can be the same or parallel, intersect in one point, or have no intersection. Now, I want to know the states of two lines in $\mathbb R^4$ space.

Comment: Same as in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: parallel lines also have no intersection. you probably meant skew lines.

Comment: @vasili yes i mean skew lines.

Comment: By the way, you should use mathjax in the questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that two lines in the affine space $\mathbb R^4$ can be seen *like inside* a 3-dimensional affine subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ or a 2-dimensional affine subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ (or even a 1-dimensional subspace, if they are the same). Specifically, they live inside the affine subspace generated by the direction vectors of the lines and a vector constructed from a point of every line. So the only possibilities are the same as in $\mathbb R^3$.